# Cannot access Qliksense url outside Azure Vnet

Tags: azure, url, port, firewall, qliksense

I am new to Qliksense and Azure. We have installed Qliksense in Azure Virtual machine. Trying to access the Qliksense hub/QMC URL (https://xxx.intranet.myclient.com/hub) from the internet/outside the azure Network, but was unsuccessful. The url is working well in the intranet.

Azure VM has a private ip address.

1. Created inbound rules in NSG(Network Security group) at Azure to open ports 443,80, 4244.
   2.Created firewall inbound rule in VM server to open ports 80, 443, 4244, 4243, 4248, 4242
2. Added the url to the host white list at the virtual proxy side in Qlik QMC

May I know what wrong am doing or what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you want to access qlik url to work from the internet, you need a public IP address attached to the Azure VM or load balancer service like Azure application gateway in front of Azure VM with a public IP address. Refer to [this](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/April2019/Subsystems/PlanningQlikSenseDeployments/Content/Sense_Deployment/Azure-deployment-example.htm). If you have no public IP address, you can directly deploy one and attach to the VM network interface on the Azure portal. Try to restart the Azure VM or refresh VM.

Then, make sure you have a DNS map which is pointing FQDN `xxx.intranet.myclient.com` to your VM public IP address. You can try to access the Qliksense hub/QMC URL like `https://PublicIPaddress/hub` first.

Also, you can run the command `netstat -anbo` as the administrator in the CMD to check if the port is listening on Qliksense service. Try to `telnet` or `Test-NetConnection` the Qliksense URL before you access the Qliksense URL on the remote machine.

If the above all are no effect, you can look at [this](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-on-AWS-Azure/Installation-Virtual-machine-port-80-in-use-by-system/td-p/1551004). Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have mentioned to our network team to provide a public IP address. Will provide an update if this works so that other users can get help from this solution.